# view helpers in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

My problem is when i want to show my image i didn't get anything, for more details : i have two entities with **OneToOne** relationship, this is my view :

```
<?php 
                $form = $this->form;
                $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url(
                        'blog',
                        array(
                                'action' => 'edit',
                                'id'     => $this->id,
                        )
                ));
                $form->setAttribute('class', 'contact_form');
                $form->setAttribute('method', 'post');
                $form->setAttribute('enctype','multipart/form-data');
                $form->prepare();
            ?>
            <?php  
               echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
               $image = $form->get('image');
            ?>
                    // here i have the problem 
             <img src="../../../upload/<?php $image->get('url')?>" alt=">
```

i tried everything with `<?php $image->get('url')?>` but i didn't get my url !!

Comment: Ok @Sam if you have any solution it will be good, i am beginner in Zend Framework and i want some help at least this time.

Comment: If you want to display the value of an element, you need to access the value of an element. This is all the help you should need.

Answer (score 2):

As the error message states you can not echo a Object. Your Form Object does have a few method's which you can find within the [Zf2 Element Documentation.](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.elements.html)

in your case I assume you want to get the "src" attribute of your image tag so you would have to:

```
echo $image->getAttribute('src');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to echo the value being returned from $image->get().

Comment: thnx @oxtub but we can't do that because i will got this error : Object of class Zend\Form\Element could not be converted to string